# Bounded linear operators and finding the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm attemping to show the following is a bounded linear operator, with the supremum norm on f and g:

$$O_g(f) =\int_0^2 f(x)g(x)dx $$ and $$  f,g \in C[0,2]$$

and then I have to find its norm, given that $g=(x-1)$ and $f=(x-1)^i$ where $i$ is a large odd $\mathbb Z$.

I know what to do, but not how to do it. So far I have that |$O_g(f)| \leq \int_0^2||f(t)g(t)||dt$ , and am sort of stuck. How do I handle this integral? I worked through it making a mistake and am confident I know how to solve the problem, but can't quite sort out this bit.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on a compact set, so they are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The norm of $O_g$ is $\int_0^{2} |g(x)|dx$. First note that $|O_g(f)| \leq \|f\| \int_0^{2} |g(x)|dx$ (where $\|f\|$ is the sup norm of $f$). Next we note that if we could choose $f$ to be sign of $g$ (i.e. $f(x) =1$ if $g(x) >0, -1$ if $g(x) <-0$ and $0$ if $g(x)=0$) then we would have $O_g(f)=\int_0^{2} |g(x)|dx$. This would complete the proof since sup norm of this $f$ is $1$. However, this $f$ is not a continuous function. To make the argument precise we need a theorem about approximation of integrable functions by continuous functions: For any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a continuous function $h$ such that $\|h\| \leq  1$ and $\int_0^{2} |f(x)-h(x)|dx <\frac {\epsilon} {\|g\|}$. I will let you complete the proof using this.